# Factory Girl created objects not clearing in between tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm being held up implementing tests with a slight confusion. With User.create I can create and save in multiple tests:

```
should "test something" do
  u1 = User.create(:first_name => "Fred", :last_name => "Flintstone")
  assert true
end

should "test something else" do
  u1 = User.create(:first_name => "Fred", :last_name => "Flintstone")
  assert true
end
```

but using Factory.create, it throws a ActiveRecord duplicate entry error:

```
should "test something" do
  Factory.create(:amanda_levy)
  assert true
end

should "test something else" do
  Factory.create(:amanda_levy)
  assert true
end
```

Error: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry"

What gives?

Comment: what is :amanda_levy, this is probably the source of the problem

Comment: that's just Factory Girl syntax for Factory.create(:factory_name)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the the following line in your spec_helper:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

That tells rspec/ test::unit to start a transaction at the start
of every test case, and issue a rollback when it's over.

Comment: Worth checking also that your test database supports transactions. For example, mysql using the default MyISAM storage engine does not.